# How to bind CheckBox IsChecked to ListBox of CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I have a list of check boxes and a single check box that acts as CheckAll/UncheckAll for all items in the listbox.

How can I make the chkAll Check Box checked if all the items are checked in the listbox binding ?

I could create a property in the view model to achieve that. I would like to do it in the xaml code.

```
 <ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding mySource}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedProperty}">
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>


<CheckBox Name="chkAll" Content="CheckAll/UnCheckAll" IsChecked ={}/>
```

Comment: @LynnCrumbling How this link answers my question :) My bindings for the list works fine and as expected. The issue is in the stand alone checkbox chkAll.

Comment: I'd make a public property in the viewmodel that has a setter; when the value for that setter = true, loop through all items in mySource and set IsSelected = true. (Note: you'll need to set this same property = false if any of the items is unchecked.) You aren't going to be able to do this in pure xaml.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to have a higher-level view model property that reflects this additional state. The state has three possible values too, so be sure to set `IsThreeState` to true, and bind it to a `Nullable<bool>`.

Then in this property's setter, you can update all the other checkbox properties.

For each item's `IsSelectedProperty`, you'll need to update the three-state property too.